# Efficient paging in SQL Server 2000 using rowcount

Tags: sql-server-2000, pagination, rowcount

I'm seeking solutions to do paging in **sql server 2000** and from all the research done such far, most solutions on **sql server 2000** platform use the same technique as [illustrated here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml) by Greg Hamilton on 4GuysfromRolla

The issue with his approach is that he's using the "employeeid" for sorting, which is an auto increment identity column. If I want to sort on some other columns that might have null values or non unique values, it will fall apart.

The only solution that works is the solution mentioned in that same article using a tempdb table by "Dave Griffiths".

My question is, anyone knows any other solutions that works without the need for tempdb and handles non unique or null column data?

Thanks

***Note:**. It has to be a SQL Server 2000 solution. I need the lowest common denominator.